# Bootstrap 4 - wrapping card image inside anchor tags creates white space in IE 11

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following bootstrap 4 markup for a card where the image is wrapped inside an anchor tag:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/myimage.jpg" >
  </a>
  <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

When viewed in IE 11 I get a large white space underneath the image. In Chrome, Edge and Firefox everything displays fine.

When I remove the anchor tags around the image then it seems to work fine and the white space disappears.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: did you try moving the `class="card-img-top"` to the a tag?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Use `height:100%` on the image

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i find the solution...

just add below three line css in your file.

```css
.card a{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/myimage.jpg" >
  </a>
  <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```